# "importing 'android' gradle project" in Flutter project make lots of problems apper in Project Structure - Problems

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, import

Every time when I open my flutter project in Android Studio "importing 'android' gradle project" process begins.
[image]
Besides it takes lots of time to finish it clutter Project Structure - Problems window with 100+ problems.
[image]

When I run "Remove All Unused Libraries", restart the IDE and cansel "importing 'android' gradle project" there are no Problems and everything works fine. When I don't cancel  "importing 'android' gradle project" after restarting IDE all problems reapper.
Could you please explain:

1. What's the meaning of "importing 'android' gradle project" if any?
2. How do I once and for all get rid of "Library xyz is not used" problems?

Running "dart pub cache repair" command and cleaning the cashes change nothing.